# Programmatically alter SSAS SSDT-BI (BIDS) project

Tags: c#, ssas, ssas-2012, amo

I am writing a C# application that needs to alter a SSAS cube project. The alterations are mainly adding dimension members and measures, but could potentially go beyond that.
I can use Analysis Management Objects (AMO) to add new dimensions, measures etc. after the project has been deployed, but I am looking for a way to do this in a dwproj project on disc. 
I could go through the project XML files and alter them directly, but this could be a likely source of errors, and it would be extremely sensitive to product updates from Microsoft.
Alternatively, I could deploy the project to an SSAS server temporarely, do the alteration via AMO, and then regenerate the project from the server. Is there a way to generate a dwproj from a SSAS server database programmatically? (Not via the SSDT-BI project template).

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you use AMO against the deployed database on the server then create the SSDT-BI project as needed. I don't know of a way to create the project files programmatically.

You could of course build a Visual Studio add-in to add dimensions and measures to the project inside Visual Studio like [BIDS Helper](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io) does (example feature source code [here](https://github.com/BIDeveloperExtensions/bideveloperextensions/blob/bidshelper-vsix/SSAS/DataTypeDiscrepancyCheckPlugin.cs)) but that is overkill in my opinion and you will spend half of your time on Visual Studio add-in plumbing not your core business need.